# How to make regex expression to find all words after (africa)

Tags: regex, regex-group

I Have text and I want to use regex expression to find all words come after (Africa is):
my code

```
pattern = r'\africa\sis\s\w+'

re.findall(pattern,a)

the results should contain africa is (some words)

but I got this error

error: bad escape \i at position 0
```

Comment: You should not escape `a`

Comment: Only escape special characters. As per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), *hanged in version 3.6: Unknown escapes in pattern consisting of '\' and an ASCII letter now are errors*